# get selected tags text with select2 AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tags, selected, ui-select2

How do I get user selected multiple tags with angularjs, taking in consideration the following snippet

**Markup**

```
<input type="hidden" ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="list_of_string" style="width:100%" />
                                <small>hint: start to type with  a</small>
```

**Angular scope**

```
$scope.list_of_string = [];

$scope.select2Options = {
    data: function() {
        api.categories().then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        });

        return {'results': $scope.data};
    },
    'multiple': true,
    formatResult: function(data) {

        return data.text;
    },
    formatSelection: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code as a fiddle or something similar?

Comment: I will upload on plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `<input .../>` to `<select> </select>`

like

```
<select multiple ui-select2 ng-model="list_of_string" style="width: 100%">
    <option ng-repeat="option in data">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```